# No such file or directory. Cucumber::Runtime::FeaturesLoader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Rails 3.2.14 app. Repo with cucumber autotests inside "vendor" folder.
I need to parse `*.feature` files.

Thor task

```
require './config/environment'
require "gherkin/tag_expression"
require "cucumber/runtime"
require 'cucumber'

class DB < Thor

  include Thor::Actions

  #...

  desc 'test', 'test'
  def generate_reports
    tag_expression = Gherkin::TagExpression.new(["@mytag"])
    file_list = get_list_of_files("features/myproject/")
    features_object = Cucumber::Runtime::FeaturesLoader.new(file_list, [], tag_expression)
    puts features_object.features[0].feature_elements.inspect
  end
end
```

The error when I run task:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:58:in `initialize': No such file or directory - widget.feature. Please create a widget.feature directory to get started. (Errno::ENOENT)
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:58:in `open'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:58:in `source'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:37:in `parse'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:28:in `block in load'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `each'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:26:in `load'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.15/lib/cucumber/runtime/features_loader.rb:14:in `features'
  from /home/user/work/interface/lib/tasks/db.thor:56:in `test'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/runner.rb:36:in `method_missing'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:29:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:126:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/bin/thor:6:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/thor:23:in `load'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/thor:23:in `<main>'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

When I make that actions in IRB everything works. 
What is the problem? Or maybe is there a better way to parse feature files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber is telling you that it can't find the file you've asked it to parse, I suspect that your `get_list_of_files` method is returning a list of `.feature` files without the path?

Compare these two code samples, where a feature `features/a_feature.feature` exists

```
f = Cucumber::FeatureFile.new("a_feature.feature")
f.parse([], [])

#=> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - a_feature.feature. Please create a a_feature.feature directory to get started.
```

Compare to...

```
f = Cucumber::FeatureFile.new("features/a_feature.feature")
f.parse([], [])

#=> Cucumber::Ast::Feature(...)
```

I think if your `get_list_of_files` returns the correct relative path, or a full path for each feature file it should work as you expect.